# Python: best way to find out from which set the results of `symmetric_difference` are from?

Tags: python, set, symmetric-difference

What is the best practice for finding out from which set the results of `symmetric_difference` are from?

```
intersect = s1.symmetric_difference(s2)
```

The result should look like

```
{'34':'s1', '66':'s2'}
```

Where '34','66' are the unique items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this most cleanly, the following should work:

```
intersect = s1.symmetric_difference(s2)
result = dict([(i, ("s1" if i in s1 else "s2")) for i in intersect])
```

Comment: `dict([(x,y) for ...])` can be better written as `dict((x,y) for ...)`.  The additional brackets create an unnecessary list that is then immediately converted to a dictionary, so not using them will both look cleaner and run faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
{x : 's1' for x in intersect if x in s1} + {x : 's2' for x in intersect if x in s2}
```

or

```
{x : ('s1' if x in s1 else 's2') for x in intersect}
```